# Questions about $y'_x=-\frac{f'_x}{f'_y}$ for implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was reading in my book that if we have $f(x,y)=0$ and want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with respect to $x$ we use the formula $y'_x=-\cfrac{f'_x}{f'_y}$.
I am not very familiar with this formula so I have these questions:

Question $1$:How we can prove this formula works?

Question$2$:Is it really necessary to memorize this formula to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ ? I want to know your experience in finding derivative in this form. I think it is easier to differentiate both sides of the equation instead of memorizing some formula. so is it really useful formula?(do you recommend to ignore this formula or use it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to pull out this formula. One is using the 'implicit function theorem' and the second is using the concept of 'gradient'. The first requires a little multivariable calculus and the second requires a little vector calculus.

For the gradient way, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933529/an-alternate-to-implicit-function-theorem)

For the multivariable way (implicit function theorem), [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEcnE0XUQIg&list=PL8erL0pXF3JZZTnqjginERYYEi1WpLE_V&index=52&ab_channel=ProfGhristMath)

Comment: I was thinking to my self maybe it comes from the taking differential of the equation : $f(x,y)=0$ we get $f_xdx+f_ydy=0$ therefor $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{f_x}{f_y}$ is it correct? (so it is not really memorizing a formula !)

Comment: Well it's a slight bit more complex than that. The idea is that if you have f(x,y) = some exp in x and y, that's a 3-d surface. Now, if you fix that's output like f(x,y) = c  then this constant output set corresponds to a curve in the x-y plane

Comment: Now, consider a curve such that this function is zero for all points on the curve (i.e: f(x,y) = 0 ) , now if you write the differential the derivative of function using chain rule along this curve (assuming y can be written as function of x:

$$ \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{ \partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{ \partial F}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Now, $ \frac{df}{dx}$ is zero  as we change 'x' coz by definition the function is zero at all point in 'x', rearrange for dy/dx

Comment: You can find multivariable chain rule here,(but instead of 't' our parameter is 'x' here)

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/differentiating-vector-valued-functions/a/multivariable-chain-rule-simple-version

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: I mean, the way you said is correct only (differential thing) but to actually explain what is going on that's a bit more to think of [see proof for 2-d case in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)

Comment: Hmm, these are all advanced math I think! I am not at this level in math but I try to understand them.

Comment: It sort of is but I'm sure you'll be able to get it if you spend a while on it